# Unknown network connections in nethogs (is it safe?)

Tags: networking, netstat, safety

It's about a month that I see some unknown connections in `nethogs` and I tried to understand what program is responsible for them but I failed.

1. I'm not sure but it seems that my Internet connection becomes laggy or lost every time this connections appear
2. They only appear for a short time and as I notice them they are gone.
3. I'm from Iran. Every time these IPs show up, I can only open websites that are inside Iran (I mean the servers are in Iran) and I can't open any other website! That's really strange.

Are these normal connections? If true, what are those for? If false what should I do?

```
192.168.1.2:53483-91.98.103.126:80
```

i was trying some of security tips.... i activated UFW and tried some tips from here:
 https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics 
(activated IP spoofing protection).

Today the Internet problem happened again. I lost my access to non-Iranian servers/sites but the IPs didn't appeared in the NetHogs and the connection problem lasted for several minutes instead of seconds.

I will update this post with more details(if any) hope you can understand the exact situation.

Mint 17.1 Cinnamon

-marked in red-:

[image: image1]

-marked in red-:

[image: image2]

Comment: First of all, please don't use screenshots unless absolutely necessary.  They are not searchable and neither can the text be copied.
`nethogs` groups bandwidth by process, so what process is running.  Maximize the window to see more of the PROGRAM column.  Also a quick check of the IP addresses using a WhoIs query shows that the first is going to Iran, while the second is going to Google.

Comment: sorry for screen shot and thank you for the comment. i did maximized the window but the only thing that appeared was the IP. i noticed that the DEV for other connections is wlan0 but the DEV column for  this connection is empty

Comment: This is the complete line: 192.168.1.2:53483-91.98.103.126:80